# How to write PHP Unit test for a API Wrapper, for an external API, by checking if the requests the Class makes fit a pattern

Tags: php, api, unit-testing

I am currently working on a API Wrapper for an internal API. I have found a lot of answers when searching for how to test an API, but not an wrapper.

The problem is, that the API (of course) need authentication and is an internal API developed by another team.

The tests should be independent from the API itself and not really call teh API.

The tests need to work without a connection to the internal API, but I know, what valid requests from the class would look like, given a certain input.

My first thought was a solution, where I call an function of the API wrapper class and checking if the (curl) requests the class makes are equal to a predefined value. E.g. checking the JSON body of one or more POST requests is the same as I would expect.

How would you recommend implementing such a test?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help :)

Comment: Just FYI in the title it says external API, because for this scenario it should be treated as such, as connecting to the API for testing is not an option.

Comment: Look into PHP Unit's [test doubles](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/7.4/test-doubles.html). If you make proper use of a concept known as "dependency injection", you can use a mock object in place of your ordinary API class and perform assertions on method calls, received data, etc. without any requests to the API ever being triggered. In this way you can ensure that the wrapper is behaving as it should without any external side-effects.